# Only SAML token validation

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I have a SP(Service Provider implemented using Spring SAML), I want the SP will send the authentication SAML token to another service application .Now I need   validate(only) the token against the IDP at service apilcation end. How can I achieve this?

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism in the standard SAML profiles which allows validation of issued SAML assertions against IDP servers. Validation is typically done by recipients of the tokens - by validating XML signature on the assertion and verifying it was performed using a trusted certificate.

There are also additional standards which prescribe issuing and usage of SAML assertions for such use-cases, for example [WS-Trust](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.4/ws-trust.html), but it tends to get complex pretty fast.

You might also want to look into [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) standard, which is a good way to achieve machine-to-machine authentication, performed on-behalf of a user.