# WebService application as service provider

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

Is it possible for a WEBSERVICE application to behave like a Service provider and get a validated saml token from IDP?
Any example or any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: See answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096638/only-saml-token-validation